# Firebase Storage Rules - How to implement different read and write rules

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement rules for loading images to the gallery in my app. All users should be able to read, but only users with type 'admin' should be able to upload / write images to storage.

I've been able to get the rules to work with several other directories inside Storage, but always where the read and write rules are the same.

For example, in a directory where users upload their own documents, I've implemented a rule which says that to read or write a file to the directory, the directory must have the same name as the uid OR have admin rights.

The code which is working is:

```
match /userUploadedDocuments/{uid}/{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if (root.child('CustomerDatabase').child(request.auth.uid).child('userType').val() == 'admin')
    || request.auth.uid == uid;
}
```

The code which isn't working is:

```
match /gallery {
  match /{allImages=**} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow write: if (root.child('CustomerDatabase').child(request.auth.uid).child('userType').val() == 'admin');
  }
}
```

Firebase will accept this code, but it fails whenever I try to write to the directory.

Your help would be very welcome.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to read data out of Realtime Database to determine the user type.  This isn't supported.  The best you can do is read data from the authenticated user account custom claims.

Comment: Thanks for for the feedback. I does seem to be working in the first case, but maybe I need to test it a little more vigorously. The authenticated user account claims looks like it will do, although it looks a little cumbersome. Thanks again.